# Reference request: book on abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation, geometric-measure-theory

I'm having a hard time understanding most of the material covered in chapter 1 of [Federer's GMT book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-62010-2#toc) (it includes tensor products, graded algebra, exterior algebra); this is mostly because I'm not that familiar with abstract algebra.  Does anyone know a good algebra book that would go well together with Federer's book? I've done the usual abstract algebra program at my uni, that is, groups, rings, fields up to Galois theory.

Comment: A suspect that a mixture of Lang's Algebra (which is a good reference, hard to learn from) and Dummit and Foote (which is good to learn from but very wordy). Although this is perhaps an odd suggestion, I think the appendices to Lee's Smooth Manifolds (which is not at all about algebra, but which still discusses the *geometric* side of exterior algebras) might also be a useful reference.

Comment: Federer is really terse at the beginning, you don't need a lot of abstract algebra knowledge. Actually, you probably shouldn't read an abstract algebra book. Very basics in multi-linear algebra will suffice. There is a monograph "Tensor Spaces and Exterior Algebra" by Takeo Yokonuma which will have all that's needed to guide you. Like I said, some things in Federer are just very terse so don't get discouraged.

Comment: You don’t want an algebra book. Learn about tensors and differential forms from a differentiable manifolds perspective. You need some differential geometry knowledge (along with plenty of measure/integration theory). You might also warm up with some friendlier GMT sources, such as Frank Morgan’s introduction.

Comment: The chapter "Homological integration theory" requires some homological algebra.

Comment: @Jakobian Thanks! The monograph you mentioned seems to be what I need.